# Is it possible to somehow edit product option names via Shopify REST API (2022-07)?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I tried to do it like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, testurl.'products/4383793250431.json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');

$product = array(
    "product"=>
        array(
            //"id"=>4383793250431,
            "options"=>
            array(
                "id"=>5688792809599,
                "name"=> "Material1",
            )
        ));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($product));

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'X-Shopify-Access-Token: '.TEST_ADMIN_API_TOKEN;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
"{"errors":{"base":["could not delete option because it has more than 1 value"]}}
```

Despite the fact that the interface does not have any problems with this:

[Successful renaming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbdL4.png)

Comment: all you have to do is send all the option values in the request also

Comment: @hamzasgd, unfortunately the result hasn't changed.

Comment: can you show the code again how you are sending it?

Comment: @hamzasgd, I just tried to add this in "options":
`"values"=>
array(
"Standard Wallpaper (130gsm) | £24/m²",
"Premium Ultra-Matte Wallpaper (155gsm) | £26/m²",
"Smooth Vinyl Wallpaper (255gsm) | £29/m²",
"Self-Adhesive Wallpaper (275gsm) | £33/m²"
 )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the error was referring to the 2nd product option, which is not mentioned in the request.
As you can see in the screenshot, the product has the "Size" option, it must also be passed in the request, otherwise the API tries to remove this option.
The correct request looks like this:

```
$product = array(
    "product"=>
        array(
            "options"=>
            array(
                array(
                    "id"=>5688792809599,
                    "name"=> "Material3",
                    ),
                    array(
                        "id"=>5688792842367,
                        "name"=> "Size",
                )
            )      
        ));
```